# Variable associated to "Optimization terminated successfully" in scipy.optimize.fmin_cg?

Tags: scipy

I am using scipy.optimize.fmin https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html.

What is the variable associated to "Optimization terminated successfully"?

I need it such that I could write something like:

if "optimization not succesful" then "stop the for loop"

Thank you.

Comment: `warnflag` is a good guess.

Comment: I tried, but if I write warnflag, it says it is not defined

Comment: Please share this code, and also the error message.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-79d6c013abce> in <module>()
----> 1 warnflag

NameError: name 'warnflag' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the docs.

You are interested in `warnflag` (as mentioned by cel in the comments), the 5th element returned, so just index 
 (0-indexing in python!) the result with `result[4]` to obtain your value.

The docs also say that some of these are only returned when called with argument `full_output=True`, so do this.

Simple example:

```
import numpy as np
args = (2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10)  # parameter values
def f(x, *args):
    u, v = x
    a, b, c, d, e, f = args
    return a*u**2 + b*u*v + c*v**2 + d*u + e*v + f
def gradf(x, *args):
    u, v = x
    a, b, c, d, e, f = args
    gu = 2*a*u + b*v + d     # u-component of the gradient
    gv = b*u + 2*c*v + e     # v-component of the gradient
    return np.asarray((gu, gv))
x0 = np.asarray((0, 0))  # Initial guess.
from scipy import optimize
res1 = optimize.fmin_cg(f, x0, fprime=gradf, args=args, full_output=True)  # full_output !!!
print(res1[4])  # index 4 !!!
```